# postgresql where conditional, mixin "AND" "OR"

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I need to get the data from a DB and match two columns: Key and name, but I cant get it to work, if I use AND on both conditions:

```
...where lower(items.key_) SIMILAR TO lower('memory.size')
   and lower(items.name) SIMILAR TO lower('Memory Utilization%')
   and history.clock > '2020-08-12 03:05:32'
```

the query doesnt work because when items.key is similar to memory.size, items.name will never be similar to "Memory Utilization", so I try to do it with OR:

```
...where lower(items.key_) SIMILAR TO lower('memory.size')
   or lower(items.name) SIMILAR TO lower('Memory Utilization%')
   and history.clock > '2020-08-12 03:05:32'
```

But it doesnt work either.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIMILAR TO` is not really the operator you want.  You are using `%`, so that suggests `LIKE`:

```
where (lower(items.key_) like lower('memory.size') or
       lower(items.name) like lower('Memory Utilization%')
      ) and history.clock > '2020-08-12 03:05:32'
```